# How to display data from custom table in wordpress database?

Tags: database, sanitization

I want to retrieve data from custom table, that I've made inside the wordpress database and display it in a wordpress page , like posts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example code that will get the data and then display it:

```
    global $wpdb;
    // this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "your_table_name";
    // this will get the data from your table
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
?>
<ul>
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
        <li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</ul>
<?php
```

It's good practice to use unique names for variables and functions, so you may want to add a unique prefix to all your variables or functions IE: ($prefix_table_name where "prefix" would be something unique such as the abbreviation of your theme or plugin.)

Reference - [wpdb - codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code for display all the records from database in wordpress. For this firstly need to create a file.php inside your selected wordpress folder and then use this file as a template. And this code will work perfectly Thank you all.

```
<?php /* Template Name: your template name */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>FULL NAME</th>
     <th>BRANCH NAME</th>
     <th>E-MAIL ID</th>
     <th>Mobile Number</th>
     <th>Course</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Zip Code</th>
    </tr>

      <?php

        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_example");
        foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>
          <tr>
                  <td>  <?php echo $print->id; ?> </td>
                  <td><?php echo $print->firstname; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $print->branch ; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $print->email; ?> </td>
                  <td><?php echo $print->mobile; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $print->course; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $print->address; ?> </td>
                  <td><?php echo $print->city; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $print->zip ; ?> </td>
          </tr>
            <?php }
      ?>

</table>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. Please re-read it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for `$wpdb`. You'll need to write all your own functions and such. I strongly recommend sticking to the established naming conventions (stuff like `the_blah` and `get_blah`, maybe with a prefix) for ease of readability and for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of @Kirill Fuchs's answer. If you use this code on shortcode this may create a problem. It may display the outputs in wrong order. To avoid the I used return instead of echo. Try to do this on shortcode this way:

```
add_shortcode('custom_db', function(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'liveshoutbox';
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ 
    $f_name = $retrieved_data->column_name;
    $f_text = $retrieved_data->another_column_name;
}
    $output = '<div class="wrap">
                    <h2>Table of clients.</h2>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>
                        <td>'. $f_name .'</td>
                        <td>'. $f_text .'</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>            
                </div>';
    return $output;
} );
```

Comment: You can also use output buffer to collect the html for return. Use ob_start(); at the beginning and return ob_get_clean();

Comment: No need to write many lines in single quote.