# Retrieving and Displaying Data From a Table

Tags: php, database

At the moment, I have created a code that retrieves data from the database and displays it. However, for some reason, I cannot see the files I want to retrieve on my page. My goal is that the data gets retrieved from the database, and is displayed on the webpage. I do not need to make a connection with the database since Wordpress does that automatically.

My code:

```php
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpex_programma; " );
print_r($retrieve_data);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

My question: the data is not shown and I believe it is not retrieved. How can I fix that? The table name is correct, and I have data in my database tabel. The `print_r($retrieve_data)`returns the following:
`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 35 [naam] => /public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/FilesUpload/Country Kickin 1.mp3 ) )`

My query log:

[image]

My database structure:
[image]

New:

```php
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpex_programma; " );
print_r($retrieve_data);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->id;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->naam;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: That looks OK to me. Note that your $table_name variable will be "wp_wpex_programma", because you're prefixing $wpdb->prefix, but you're not using that anyway. Can you use your database tools to check the query is being run on the database OK and returning results? Or e.g. the Query Monitor plugin?

Comment: Hi @Rup, yes the query works fine on my database when I run it. Should I just delete: ````$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";````?

Comment: You can delete the line but it shouldn't matter either way. I meant when WordPress runs the query, e.g. the MySQL query log or a profiler to check the actual SQL that is being run on the database, in case it's changed the SQL string somehow - but I don't think it does. I'd try the Query Monitor plugin though if you haven't already.

Comment: @Rup, I will download the plugin and let you know what it tells me

Comment: @Rup, I added a pic to my question. Is that the query log?

Comment: Yes, more or less (I meant MySQL's own one, but this is the same information). You'll need to scroll down to find your new query.

Comment: @Rup, it also says that ````$Column_name```` and ````$another_column_name```` and ````$as_many_columns_as_you_have```` are undefined properties.

Comment: (Note this does highlight one common problem: WP is making repeat DB calls for options that don't have a value. Most options that have a value are loaded by the first autoload call, but this doesn't autoload unset options. I'm not sure what the best fix for this is: set null / empty values for all the other ones as autoload=true)

Comment: @Rup, I added my most recent query in my question as a pic. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Great: you can see Rijen=1 so the query did return some data. It might be worth putting a `print_r($retrieve_data)` on the page to be sure, and to check the format you're getting. But it's hopefully just a case of debugging your for loop now.

Comment: Awesome! I added ````print_r($retrieve_data)```` in my code. It does show me the file. It shows the following: ````Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 34 [naam] => /tmp/php06Iitg ) )````. As you can see, it also shows the id. @Rup

Comment: However, it still does not echo it the way it is supposed to. It is supposed to show them in the ````<li>```` tags. @Rup

Comment: @Parsa_237 can you please use the edit link to add in the actual code rather than placeholders, as well as the table schema of the table you're attempting to query. We have no idea what the column names are or what kind of data is in them, so it's not possible to verify if you've written the code correctly or incorrectly. Also include the output of `print_r($retrieve_data);` in your question. Most people don't read the comments, so put it in the original question

Comment: @TomJNowell, check the new edit. I put it in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```php
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
```

Here, the code tries to output the data in the `column_name` column, but there is no column  in the table by that name.

Likewise, there is no `another_column_name` or `as_many_columns_as_you_have` columns in your table.

We know that the query pulls in the data, because when you used `print_r` we could see the data. We also know that when we did that we didn't see fields named `column_name`, we saw fields named `id` and `naam`.

After a little digging, it looks like you took a generic example from here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54641/736

But didn't make any modifications to match your table. The example wasn't a copy paste work anywhere code block, such a thing does not exist for what you want.

Your table has `id` and `naam` columns, these are what the code should be using, not `another_column_name` or `as_many_columns_as_you_have`

Comment: Yes, I was looking to show you that I got it from there. Thanks for the answer, Tom. Please check my edit. Is that how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Also, it still shows the whole path + id, not only the file name. Wait I'll show you.

Comment: If it works then it works,  you'd have to test it, just be wary that your question may be confusing to other people if you update the code examples in it with fixes

Comment: Displaying just the filename and not the full path is something you can ask  about on stackoverflow as it's just modifying a string in PHP

Comment: Ok great, thank you Tom.