# Displaying file from database

Tags: php, database

I have made the following code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpex_programma; " );
print_r($retrieve_data);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

The code makes sure the files get retrieved from the database. The file is saved by the path. I know that the file gets retrieved, because when I use `print_r($retrieve_data)` the id and name get shown.

However, the file is not displayed (it should display the file name, and not the path). How do I accomplish this?

What I see now is:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 35 [naam] => /public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/FilesUpload/Country Kickin 1.mp3 ) )`

While it should just be "Country Kicking 1.mp3".

Question: How can I make sure that my filenames are displayed?

For more info, see my other question: [Retrieving and displaying data from a Wordpress database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360541/retrieving-and-displaying-data-from-a-wordpress-database?noredirect=1#comment524991_360541)

My query log:

[image]

Greetings,

Parsa

Comment: How is this different from your other question? Are they duplicates? I see your PHP code is just using placeholders, and you've edited out the actual code, this makes it extremely difficult if not impossible to debug what your code is doing

Comment: No, they are different questions. This is all the code I am using for retrieving and displaying the code. Displaying the files is not working.

Comment: The question is almost identical, and the PHP code refers to things like `column_name` and `another_column_name`, is this your actual code that's running? Or have you changed it for WPSE to hide details? The question refers to files, but there are no references to files in the code, it's very confusing

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, the other question literally says `I cannot see the files I want to retrieve on my page. ` which is what this question is asking, if they are different I cannot see the difference

Comment: @TomJNowell ok :|